# TEmbeddedWB and background color

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, delphi-xe

How i can change the defult backgound color (clWhite) of a [TEmbeddedWB](http://www.bsalsa.com/product.html) component while is not showing any page?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That could be done by loading a default page when the form is created (The quick way):

```
function ColorToHTML(const Color: TColor): string;
var
  ColorRGB: Integer;
begin
  ColorRGB := ColorToRGB(Color);
  Result := Format('#%0.2X%0.2X%0.2X',
    [GetRValue(ColorRGB), GetGValue(ColorRGB), GetBValue(ColorRGB)]);
end;

WebBrowser1.Navigate(Format('about:<body bgcolor="%s" style="overflow:hidden"/>', [ColorToHTML(clRed)]));
```

Or the more common way (`TWebBrowser`/`TEmbeddedWB`):

```
uses ActiveX, MSHTML;
procedure LoadDocFromString(ABrowser: TWebBrowser; const HTMLString: WideString);
var
  v: OleVariant;
  HTMLDocument: IHTMLDocument2;
begin
  if not Assigned(ABrowser.Document) then
  begin
    ABrowser.Navigate('about:blank');
    while ABrowser.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE do
      Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
  HTMLDocument := ABrowser.Document as IHTMLDocument2;
  v := VarArrayCreate([0, 0], varVariant);
  v[0] := HTMLString;
  HTMLDocument.Write(PSafeArray(TVarData(v).VArray));
  HTMLDocument.Close;
end;

LoadDocFromString(WebBrowser1, Format('<body style="background-color:%s; scrollbar-base-color:%s;"/>',
  [ColorToHTML(clGray), ColorToHTML(clBlack)]));
```

`TEmbeddedWB` specific:

```
EmbeddedWB1.LoadFromString(Format('<body style="background-color:%s; scrollbar-base-color:%s;"/>',
    [ColorToHTML(clGray), ColorToHTML(clBlack)]));
```

---

**Edit:** Take a look at this tutorial: [How to customise the TWebBrowser user interface](http://www.delphidabbler.com/articles?article=18&part=1).
This explains how to customize WB using `IOleClientSite` and `IDocHostUIHandler` which also provide a default CSS to the **browser object** itself.

We can dynamically create a style sheet that knows about a form's colour and fonts and tell the browser to use it (Look at the result at part 5 of 6).

Since `TEmbeddedWB` implements `IDocHostUIHandler` you can use it's `HostCSS` property (You still need to load a blank document though):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  // Template for default CSS style
  cCSSTplt = 'body {background-color: %0:s}';
var
  FmtCSS: string;  // Stores default CSS
begin
  FmtCSS := Format(cCSSTplt, [ColorToHTML(clYellow)]);
  EmbeddedWB1.HostCSS := FmtCSS;
  EmbeddedWB1.AssignEmptyDocument;
end;
```

Please note that using `HostCSS` property with CSS style template will use this template also for pages with no CSS styling.

Answer (score 6):

Easily by setting the [`IHTMLDocument2.bgColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to a certain value from the [`color table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The following code will navigate to the *empty* page and change its background color to red. Please note, the background color you will need to set after each navigation to that *empty* page with this solution.

```
uses
  GraphUtil, MSHTML;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EmbeddedWB1.AssignEmptyDocument(True);
  (EmbeddedWB1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).bgColor := ColorToWebColorStr(clRed);
end;
```